# Select Information from All Tables

Tags: mysql, join

**EER Diagram**

[image]

**Question**

List the customer number, customer name (first and last), order number, order date, employee number, employee name (first and last), product number, product name, and order cost (product quantity * product unit price) for telephone orders (A telephone order has an associated employee) placed on January 23, 2007 and the order cost exceeds $150. Order the result by the order
cost in descending order.

**My Code**

```
SELECT
    Customer.CustNo,
    Customer.FirstName,
    Customer.LastName,
    `Order`.OrderNo,
    `Order`.OrderDate,
    Employee.EmpNo,
    Employee.FirstName,
    Employee.LastName,
    Product.ProdNo,
    Product.ProdName,
    CONCAT('$', ProductInOrder.Qty * SUBSTRING(Product.Price, 2)) AS `Order Cost`
From Customer, `Order`, Employee, Product, ProductInOrder
WHERE
    `Order`.Employee_EmpNo IS NOT NULL                          AND
    STR_TO_DATE(`Order`.OrderDate, '%m/%d/%Y') = '2007-1-23'    AND
    ProductInOrder.Qty * SUBSTRING(Product.Price, 2) > 150
ORDER BY `Order Cost` DESC;
```

**Result**

[image]

14:57:29    SELECT  Customer.CustNo,     Customer.FirstName,     Customer.LastName,     `Order`.OrderNo,     `Order`.OrderDate,     Employee.EmpNo,     Employee.FirstName,     Employee.LastName,     Product.ProdNo,     Product.ProdName,     CONCAT('$', ProductInOrder.Qty * SUBSTRING(Product.Price, 2)) AS `Order Cost` From Customer, `Order`, Employee, Product, ProductInOrder WHERE  `Order`.Employee_EmpNo IS NOT NULL       AND     STR_TO_DATE(`Order`.OrderDate, '%m/%d/%Y') = '2007-1-23' AND     ProductInOrder.Qty * SUBSTRING(Product.Price, 2) > 150 ORDER BY `Order Cost` DESC LIMIT 0, 1000   1000 row(s) returned    0.290 sec / 0.011 sec

---

**My Question**

I think there is something wrong with the code `From Customer, Order, Employee, Product, ProductInOrder`. How to join all the tables together? If I use `INNER JOIN`, it will be more complicated.

---

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It says like syntax error, which you missed the `,`

```
SELECT
    Customer.CustNo,
    Customer.FirstName,
    Customer.LastName,
    `Order`.OrderNo,
    `Order`.OrderDate,
    Employee.EmpNo,
    Employee.FirstName,
    Employee.LastName,
    Product.ProdNo,
    Product.ProdName,
    CONCAT('$', ProductInOrder.Qty * SUBSTRING(Product.Price, 2)) AS `Order Cost`
From Customer, `Order`, Employee, Product, ProductInOrder
WHERE
    `Order`.Employee_EmpNo IS NOT NULL                          AND
    STR_TO_DATE(`Order`.OrderDate, '%m/%d/%Y') = '2007-1-23'    AND
    `Order`.Cost > 150
ORDER BY `Order`.Cost DESC;
```

Comment: Codes updated but I problem is still here. =[

Comment: Still its a syntax error only, updated